# Continuously invertible operator.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $F$ be a bounded linear operator between the Hilbert spaces $H_1$ and $H_2$. Let $F$ satisfies $$\|z_1-z_2\|\leq \|F(z_1)-F(z_2)\|^t, \ t>0, \ z_1, z_2\in H_1.$$
How to show that $F$ is continuously invertible?

$F$ is one-one is clear. How to show that $F$ is onto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $H_1$ is  closed subspace of $H_2$ and $F(x)=x$ for all $x \in H_1$ then the inequality holds with $t=1$ but $F$ is not onto. So you cannot prove that $F$ is surjective.

If you assume that $F$ is onto then we can show that $F^{-1}$ is continuous as follows:  $F(x_n) \to F(x)$ implies $\|x_n-x\| \leq \|F(x_n)-F(x)\|^{t} \to 0$. This is exactly continuity of $F^{-1}$.

Comment: Ok. This means we should restrict to the range of $F$ for invertibility.

Comment: Yes, assume that $F$ is onto and prove that its inverse is continuous. This is very easy. @MittalG

Comment: Sir, would this result also holds if we fix $z_2$ to some particular element of $H_1$? I mean let $z_2=a$ for some fixed $a \in H_2$.

Comment: @MittalG I am sorry. I made some wrong statements. By linearity of $F$ the given inequality holds for all $z_1$ and $z_2$ if it holds for all $z_1$ when $z_2=0$ iff it holds for any $z_1$ for a fixed $z_2=a$.

Comment: So, you mean to say that $F^{-1}$ is continuous even if $z_2$ is fixed?

Comment: @MittalG Yes, that is true.

Comment: Please provide some input sir: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3509714/conitnuity-of-invertible-operator

Answer (score 1):

Denote $R=F(H_{1})$, we are to show that $F^{-1}:R\rightarrow H_{1}$ is continuous. Let $y_{n}\rightarrow 0$ be given, then with $z_{n}=F^{-1}(y_{n})$, we have $y_{n}=F(z_{n})$ and $\|z_{n}\|\leq\|F(z_{n})\|^{t}=\|y_{n}\|^{t}\rightarrow 0$, so $z_{n}\rightarrow 0$, in other words, $F^{-1}(y_{n})\rightarrow 0$, so $F^{-1}$ is continuous.